# Loading Images From Remote Server?

Tags: android, image

I have several images on some of my Activities, and these are all connected from Remote Server. The problem is every time I go on one of these Activities that contain images from remote sever. All of the images must load first otherwise you will get a black empty screen. Sometimes it takes about 1-5 minutes to load, and sometimes it even force close the device. Is there anyway I can fix this issue?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ImageViewimgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image01);
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://forum.roda.hr/images/customavatars/avatar10164_2.gif");
        imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);



private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have been struggling for days trying to figure this out, please help me, it would be really mean a lot to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-load-image-url-example

this should help..

and as jett try doing it in lazy with AsynTask to do the loading in background..

Comment: That is what I am using right now, and it takes forever to load

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that you should use [Thread](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) to load the images from Internet. 
Please refer to [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use thread to download image.
Refer this
[Load Image from server using thread](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/load-image-from-server-using-thread.html)
[Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: I tried the code from "Load Image from server using thread" but it seem it is not working because it force closing

Comment: There was no error but a blank screen with textview and no images at all

Comment: check are you passing the correct `imageview` and all to the `MessageHandler`. If you still have the problem post the code that you tried with your question.