# Asynchronous binding using a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter, android-contentprovider

I have a `ListView` that should display items that contain some text and an image.

The data is loaded from a local `SQLite` db file (that contains the text and image URLs).

I'd like to:

- Get the text, url from DB.
- Asynchronously download the image from the URL
- Bind both values to the `ListView` (using the `SimpleCursorAdapter`).

So far, i was able to read the values from DB, however i am not sure how i can run the bind only AFTER i have successfully loaded each image?

In other words, i'd like to asynchronously bind each element as it's loaded to the appropriate UI item.

Comment: I assume you are using a CursorLoader?

Comment: no... using an AsynTask derived class that does the downloading

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice example which shows how to this http://www.androidkit.com/loading-images-from-remote-server-over-http-on-a-separate-thread.

Briefly,

1) you need to have a `Map<Url, Bitmap>`. 
2) Have a default image that is displayed when image data from server is not available yet.
3) Have onScroll listener for your `ListView`, to know which items are currently displayed.
4) First, download those that are being displayed.
5) Once an image is downloaded, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to bind available Image to the view.
6) You can use `Softreferences` or `LRUCache` to avoid `OutofMemoryException`

Comment: @sajith the This web page is not available

Comment: @dvrm looks like they removed the page. You can look at similar questions in StackOverFlow. ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458395/loading-images-from-remote-server

Answer (score -1):

I have solved a similar problem to this. I received a XML from server and store the information in a Database. After that I populated the list using the CursorAdapter. In my case I have both images and text.

To solve the problem in the cursor adapter I did something like this:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context ctx, Cursor c) {
    TextView title =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
    title.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(yourColumName)));
    ImageView i =  (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageID); 
    String s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(youtImageColumn));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(s,i);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourRowLayout, parent, false);
    return v;
}
```

In this case the ImageLoader is an async lazy image loader gotten from here:
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList